# Trying to execute unix command in awk but receiving error

Tags: bash, awk

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; } {print $2|"od -An -vtu1"| tr -d "\n"}' test1.txt
```

I have file with

```
1|siva
2|krishna
3|  syz 5
```

I am trying to find ascii value of field 2, but below command giving me error

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; } {print $2|"od -An -vtu1"| tr -d "\n"}' test1.txt


awk: BEGIN{FS="|"; } {print $2|"od -An -vtu1 tr -d "\n"}
awk:                                                ^ backslash not last character on line
```

Expected output

```
115 105 118  97
107 114 105 115 104 110  97
32 115 121 122  32  53
```

Comment: You can't execute shell commands in `awk` simply(`system` is there for it but thing is, is there really a need? Without knowing samples of input and output we can't tell it exactly). Also please post your sample of input and sample of expected output in your post and let us know then?

Comment: echo "test" |tr -d "\n"|od -An -vtu1

output : 116 101 115 116

So I am trying to execute the above command in awk

Comment: No, that is the command. We need sample input and sample of output in you post please so that we could understand your question completely.

Comment: Why is number of `"` odd?

Comment: Below is the sample file
1|siva
2|krishna
3|  syz 5

I am trying to find the ascii for 2nd field

Comment: @sivakrishna, please post expected output too in your post.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question with sample file details

Comment: It looks like what you are trying to achieve should be written like that: `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; } {print $2}' test1.txt|od -An -vtu1| tr -d "\n"`

Comment: @vdavid, you are correct but the output coming in single line 
115 105 118  97  10 107 114 105 115 104 110  97  10  32  32 100 105 118  97  32  53 

but I want output for each row separately like below:

115 105 118  97
107 114 105 115 104 110  97
32 115 121 122  32  53

Comment: Then try something like that `awk 'BEGIN{FS="|"; } {print $2}' test1.txt|while read r; do od -An -vtu1<<<"$r"| tr -d "\n"; done`

Comment: or `cut '--delimiter=|' -f2  |od -An -vtu1 | sed  's/ 10 /\n /g'`

Comment: @vdavid the commands in your comments would leave all the output on a single line and with the newlines converted to `<blank>10`s.

Comment: @LjmDullaart That sed would leave a trailing `<blank>10` at the end of the last line of output and will leave any newlines introduced by od in its output intact. You could use `cut -d'|'` instead of the long form btw.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what your'e trying to do:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="|" }
{
    cmd = "printf \047%s\047 \047" $2 "\047 | od -An -vtu1"
    system(cmd)
}
' file
 115 105 118  97
 107 114 105 115 104 110  97
  32  32 115 121 122  32  53
```

or an alternative syntax so the output comes from awk rather than by the shell called by system():

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    cmd = "printf \047%s\047 \047" $2 "\047 | od -An -vtu1"
    rslt = ( (cmd | getline line) > 0 ? line : "N/A" )
    close(cmd)
    print $0, rslt
}
' file
1|siva| 115 105 118  97
2|krishna| 107 114 105 115 104 110  97
3|  syz 5|  32  32 115 121 122  32  53
```

Massage to suit. You don't NEED to save the result in a variable, you could just print it, but I figured you'll want to know how to do that at some point, and you don't NEED to print $0 of course.

I also assume you have some reason for wanting to do this in awk, e.g. it's part of a larger script, otherwise using awk to call system to call shell to execute shell commands is just a bad idea vs using shell to execute shell commands.

Having said that, the best shell command I can come up with to do what you want is this using GNU awk for mult-char RS:

```
$ awk -F'|' -v ORS='\0' '{print $2}' file |
    od -An -vtu1 |
    awk -v RS='  0\\s' '{gsub(/\n/,"")}1'
115 105 118  97
107 114 105 115 104 110  97
 32  32 115 121 122  32  53
```

See the comments below for how that's more robust than the first awk approach if the input contains `'$(command)'` but it does assume there's no NUL chars in your input.

Comment: You might want to be more careful to warn the OP about the security risks involved in their code. "Bad idea" is quite an understatement. (Perhaps showing them how to integrate awk into their intended pipeline without using `system()` might make more sense?)

Comment: Actually I was thinking more of just performance and complexity being the problems. Care to add a comment about security?

Comment: You're using string concatenation to substitute data into code. `$(rm -rf ~)` in your `$2`, and what happens?

Comment: It's inside single quotes (the `\047`s) so I'm hoping nothing.

Comment: `'$(rm -rf ~)'` in your `$2`, and what happens *then*? Or, more pathologically, `$(rm -rf ~)'$(rm -rf ~)'` to cover both cases

Comment: Fair enough, yes that would cause the rm to be executed.

Comment: Actually, though, it'll execute even without literal quotes in the data. The single quotes are added *by the shell printf command*, whereas the shell expansion happens *before* that printf.

Comment: I don't think so. If `$2` contains `$(rm -rf ~)` then the printf the shell sees would be `printf '%s' '$(rm -rf ~)'`. Awk isn't going to try to interpret $2 and the shell isn't involved up til that point.

Comment: Ahh -- you're right; I missed that there are multiple pairs.

Comment: I for one would be interested in seeing a robust shell solution if you feel the urge to post an answer.

Comment: There are some approaches in the comments that look adequate.

Comment: They all either remove `\n` in the wrong place or they let it be interpreted and then replace the `10` with another `\n`. I don't see any I'd actually use. One of the things I wonder about is removing the `\n` before `od` sees the string - it makes `od` ONLY interpret the chars you want interpreted which is intuitively better than having `od` interpret a char you want ignored and them removing that interpretation afterwards, but then it's relying on `od` handling input lines that don't conform to the definition of a POSIX text line so I'm not sure which is better.

Comment: One of the things that concerns me here is the unnecessary use of a whole new pipeline per line of input -- I'd rather have an inline delimiter if we can be sure that there exists some character (be it a newline or a NUL or anything else) that can't legitimately be present in the input, so we can stream it all into *just one* instance of `od`, and split its output.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK, I changed the shell script to only pass 1 line of input to `od`. See what you think...

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton  this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you're not really using any `awk`, perhaps this is easier...

```
$ while IFS='|' read -r _ f; 
  do echo -n "$f" | od -An -vtu1; 
  done < file

 115 105 118  97
 107 114 105 115 104 110  97
  32  32 115 121 122  32  53
```